# Put XML block into variable in a batch file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to put some XML code into a variable in a batch script so that I can create a file containing the XML. I also want to change one part of the XML dynamically when the script is run.

Here's how I think it should work

```
set MYUSERNAME=%USERNAME%
set string=
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<Extensibility xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AutomationExtensibility">
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio</Name>
        <Version>*</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <Addin>
        <FriendlyName>USAddin</FriendlyName>
        <Description>Union Square Addin for SQL Management Studio</Description>
        <Assembly>C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\USAddin\USAddin\bin\Debug\USAddin.dll</Assembly>
        <FullClassName>USAddin.Connect</FullClassName>
        <LoadBehavior>1</LoadBehavior>
        <CommandPreload>0</CommandPreload>
        <CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
    </Addin>
</Extensibility>

echo string > "somefile.txt"
```

Comment: Show the code you have written so far, tell us what works and where you are stuck.

Comment: The farthest I've gotten is putting a simple one line string into a variable and outputting it to a file. I got stuck on the XML because it contains quotemarks and such.

Comment: I suupose `MYUSERNAME` in the XML should be replaced with the `MYUSERNAME` given in the batch file?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't make it very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findstr` to extract the XML block:

```xml
@echo off
(
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        findstr /r /c:"^ *<.*> *$" "%~dpnx0"
    ') do (
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=%%a"
        echo !line:MYUSERNAME=%USERNAME%!
        endlocal
    )
)>"somefile.txt"

goto xmlEND

:::::::::: XML BLOCK, EACH LINE MUST START WITH < AND END WITH >

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<Extensibility xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AutomationExtensibility">
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio</Name>
        <Version>*</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <Addin>
        <FriendlyName>USAddin</FriendlyName>
        <Description>Union Square Addin for SQL Management Studio</Description>
        <Assembly>C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\USAddin\USAddin\bin\Debug\USAddin.dll</Assembly>
        <FullClassName>USAddin.Connect</FullClassName>
        <LoadBehavior>1</LoadBehavior>
        <CommandPreload>0</CommandPreload>
        <CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
    </Addin>
</Extensibility>

:xmlEND
pause
```

Comment: That will work as long as there is not any other batch code with input and output redirection on the same line.  I have few batch files that do that.  You may want to say it begins with < and ends with >